# White Screen Beeping Laptop Won't Connect To External Monitor

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron, white-screen

I have a dell inspiron (5737, I believe) Turned it on one day and the screen was white. Fiddled with it for some time and finally got it to connect to a TV. Then I turned it on the next day,it was now white AND beeping. Tried all the online troubleshooting, spent almost 2 hours turning it on and off, holding the d button, ctrl alt del-ing, and just plain smashing buttons. Somehow got it to connect, but here I am again, trying to get it to connect, but it won't stop beeping. Ctrl all del-ing makes the screen turn black for a few seconds before it goes white again and beeping.

Comment: Use a repair-shop. You might have had an electrical surge that caused some damage.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go to a repair shop (yet)! I doubt it was an electrical surge, more likely its just technology doing what its always slowly but surely doing... breaking down! :-)

Start with the basics... turn it on and just listen to/make note of the beeping. These are called "beep codes" and its telling you whats wrong, what you hear should correspond to one of the codes in this table -

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000125263/how-to-use-and-troubleshoot-the-inspiron-5737#Issue0_15

It might sound like endless beeping, but I'd guess its actually 8 beeps, which means LCD failure. Meaning, it's eBay/AliEpress parts shopping time, new laptop shopping time, or you could try live with an external display only.

Edit: "LCD failure" could just as well mean a dodgy/loose connection to the LCD. So before doing any shopping, check all the internal conections from the mainboard to the LCD, and it might come good.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to use an external monitor,  but there is no connection showing.  Yes, it is 8 beeps. Messed around inside the laptop, so now it's black screen and beeping.

Comment: To get an external display going - wait for the 8 beeps to finish, then press the F1 key or Fn + F8 (switch display) function keys to toggle to external (it could be either I'm not sure). The LCD is probably blank now because you have either dislodged (or broken) the LVDS/Display cable. Try re-seating the cable at both ends. Given you had it working on a TV before, I still suspect it's either a dodgy LCD and/or loose/broken LVDS cable, however if either of the above actions don't work for you, it might be the case that the onboard video was failing, and has now completely failed.